# garbage collection issue in young generation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

When Eden space is young generation is full, minor GC will be triggered. And in the minor GC process, non-free objects in Eden and one source Survivor space will be copied to another destination Survivor space.

My question is, if the destination Survivor space is full, how could minor GC handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible to do / complete a minor collection, then a major / full collection is performed.  This is typically done using a mark-sweep-compact algorithm rather than copying algorithm ... which is one reason why full collection is expensive.

But ultimately (if you keep filling the heap) a full collection will not be able to reclaim enough space to continue and an OOME will be thrown.  (Or if you are using `-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit`, the OOME will be thrown when the percentage time spent in GC exceeds a designated threshold.)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen! So you mean if a minor collection is triggered, and in the middle of copy process (from Eden and Survivor space) to another destination Survivor space, if we find destination Survivor space space is full, the minor collection process will be converted to a full collection, correct? Is there any related document covering the conversion of minor collection to major/full collection?

Comment: 1) That is my understanding of what happens.  2) I'm cannot point you at a document, but you could always read the OpenJDK source code to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Young generation has 3 segments Eden Space, Survivor1 and Survivor2. These are just logical divisions of Young Generation. So objects get copied from Eden Space to Survivor1 and then to Survivor2.

So minor collection in general means that collection happens in Young generation. And if Young generation is full then object gets copied to Old generation.

Again, collection is minor or major depends on multiple factors one of them is space availability in young generation. So if there is enough space in Young generation for object allocation then it will be minor collection. But if there is not enough free space in YG then the same collection can turn into major.

**Also JVM specification doesn't talk anything about garbage collection. So its left to JVM implementors to have their own strategy.**

Comment: Thanks @rai.skumar. For your comment, "So if there is enough space in Young generation for object allocation then it will be minor collection. But if there is not enough free space in YG then the same collection can turn into major.", it means even if at the beginning a minor collection is triggered, and if in the process of minor collection, if space in young generation is not enough, the minor collection will changed to a major collection?

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes you are right.