# How to stop Dropwizzard service with OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, dropwizard

I want to test some configuration which I added for case when my service crashes with OOM error. Can you please help me to find out how can I stop it with throwing OOM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just throw OutOfMemory error or allocate a lot of memory on the logic path around the critical functionality that you want to test. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880687/how-to-simulate-the-out-of-memory-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit or https://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-out-of-memory-oom-in-java-programatically/

Comment: it doesn't stop dropwizzard service

Comment: Aaa: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerRuntime.java#L260 Jersey eats the OutOfMemoryError. Try out some of their test-cases here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/tests/mem-leaks/test-cases